# Paquete o método para realizar tablas cruzadas con variables que provienen de preguntas de opción múltiple en R

Tags: r, rstudio

¿Alguien conoce qué paquete o método permite trabajar tablas cruzadas con porcentajes de varias variables al mismo tiempo?

Estoy intentando cruzar un grupo de 4 variables categóricas con otra variable también categórica. Mi objetivo es generar una tabla cruzada o de contingencia con proporciones de ambos grupos (las 4 variables vs 1 variable). Las 4 variables provienen de una sola pregunta de opción múltiple que se realizó mediante una encuesta, es por eso que las quiero usar como un solo grupo.

La función table() te permite cruzar variables pero solo con dos variables en una sola tabla

He buscado algunas soluciones y había un paquete llamado userfriendlyscience pero este ya no funciona en R. También intenté con el paquete expss pero no entiendo bien como usarlo para crear la tabla cruzada con múltiples variables.

Estoy intentando replicar una opción de spss 25 analizar>respuesta múltiple que permite generar tablas cruzadas de una con varias variables que provienen de preguntas respuestas múltiple.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Revisa la ayuda de `table()`, creo que es lo que buscas. Sino, edita tu pregunta y agrega un ejemplo de los datos y la salida que buscas.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho sí, he probado eso pero la función `table()` solo te permite cruzar dos variables en una sola tabla. Yo deseo cruzar varas vs una. Por ejemplo que en las  columnas estén las cantidades de los valores de una variable y en las filas los valores de las otras 4 variables que estoy usando. Todo eso en una tabla

Comment: Pero ahi puedes combinar `table()` con algún tipo de ciclo. ¿Por qué no nos das un ejemplo básico de los datos y de lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ya encontré una solución. En realidad se me complicaba un poco los de los ciclos. He usado el paquete expss que tiene funciones para realizar  tablas para variables de respuesta múltiple así como te proporciona spss, lo cual es más rápido